# SSIS package that loops through folder begining with oldest file

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I saw similar questions but nothing addressing my specific need. I have an SSIS package that has a For Each loop with file enumerator and a pattern match that matches a file with date time like so:

bookreview_daily_*.txt

That matches a file that is for example like so:

bookreview_daily_2016_06_30.txt. Currently I have to process each file individually begining with the oldest date. I'd like to be able to loop through the folder and process each file, begining with oldest file. If I have following files:

bookreview_daily_2016_06_30.txt

bookreview_daily_2016_07_01.txt

bookreview_daily_2016_07_02.txt

The file named bookreview_daily_2016_06_30.txt should be processed first, followed by file bookreview_daily_2016_07_01.txt and then bookreview_daily_2016_07_02.txt as the last file to be processed. Is there a clean, efficient way of accomplishing this?

- Matt

Comment: you could use a Script Task to search for files in a folder, order them and then pass the names sorted in a Loop Container to process

Comment: I agree @Roger Doger, this should be a property in the ForEach loop container in SSIS. I had a feeling I was going to have to write a script to do this, but thought I'd check here first. I'm not a .Net gal but have had to pick it up over the years for crap like this. It's a good skill to have any way. I'll post my solution once I have it, in case it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using script task.

1. Use a c# or vb.net code in script task to get the list of file present in the directory.
2. And sort them, then store the the sorted data in the object variable.
3. Then pass the object variable in For Each Loop container.
4. No it will loop through the files based on the sorting.

Also we can use array concept in scripting to achieve it.

Comment: I'm not a .net guy, I understand your flow but don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Script Task transformation of SSIS.

As the above user pointed out the crux of the logic is to read through the file names, get the datetime part and the full file name in a collection, sort the collection and then assign it to a Object Variable. Use this variable in Foreach Loop Transformation to read through the files in the desired order.

I have created a blog post on this including the logic required in a blog post - 
[Reading DateTime Stamped flat files](https://karbimantras.wordpress.com/2016/08/15/ssis-reading-datetime-stamped-flat-files/) which has further detailed description.

Comment: I understand it can be done using a Script Task, but sorting files on either filename or filedate seems like such a common requirement. I wonder why this is not a property on the Foreach Container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this with out using Script task try the below steps.

1. Create a table with FilePath,SortingValue columns.
2. Loop through all the files in foreachloop container and store the entire file path for
   each file in the table.
3. Use some SQL functions and assign values to each row( Each file).Based on your input
   the combination of Date and string functions will help you in identifying the sort.
4. Now again use foreachloop container to loop the table based on SortingValue column.
   For each loop you can get the filepath  and use it for the flat file connection
   dynamically.